# What were the first particles, according to different models?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, big-bang

At what point, and in what cosmological epoch, did particles begin to exist? What particles were they?

My understanding is that things as we know them involved the Big Bang singularity, and that the particles we currently have evolved from that through a series of symmetry-breaking events.

I am trying to understand what those stages looked like: that evolution from singularity to the particles of the standard model. And I am sure that there are multiple models as to how that evolution occurred, so I am looking for resources or descriptions of the main prevailing ideas.

Comment: @CosmasZachos sorry about the misplacement of my post. not sure i understand this site's format yet. can i ask why the "of course" for the electrons and ions? why is it "of course?" can you point me to a source that would make this answer more obvious to me? and how are ions first? ions are not elementary particles but are made up of them. how could ions without quarks? or gluons? or protons?

Comment: this is a first, but  I very much disagree with CosmasZachos's notion, and no, it wasn't electrons and ions either. blacktopshaman, for starters, see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe#Tabular_summary

Comment: @rfl I certainly did not read it as an early universe question. I hastily read it as a history of science one, wrongly...

Comment: no worries... aaaah, i see :) i've edited the question a bit to avoid that

Comment: There is at least one cosmological model that avoids any singularity, and has the (huge?) advantage of being past- and future-eternal as well, even while having some astronomical support:  Preprints of the articles describing it are freely visible at https://arxiv.org/a/poplawski_n_1.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about modeling t[he history of the universe.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe)

> At what point, and in what cosmological epoch, did particles begin to exist? What particles were the

The particles existed as far as the theory goes , even before symmetry breaking.

Let us take the [Big bang model](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html) as it has developed up to now.

[image: historuniv]

If you go to the references in the link above there are more details.

The basic assumption/hypothesis  is that the [standard model of particle physics,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) models the particles up to the time of inflation, where new physics models enter. The observations we have now are studied in this type of model , and the problems arising from inconsistency of observations, as the baryon asymmetry, are part of the ongoing studies.